# EF6 migration from 4.7 to .net Standard 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, .net-standard

I am moving my .NET Framework 4.7 based repository, which uses EF6, to a .NET Standard 2.1, also using EF6. I am using a database first approach for my model, as I have been doing since the beginning of the project.

My goal is to be able to use my repository code in my .NET Standard project with minimal changes from my .NET Framework 4.7 class library.

- When moving the `edmx` from one project to the other, it fails to import properly (copy and paste). It loses all of the nesting and just shows the classes, although it seems to be able to figure out the classes (DBSET) with no reference errors.
- I can not find an ADO.NET Entity Data model object in the .NET Standard "New item…" option.
- When I run the application it compiles, but the first time it tries to write or read anything to the database it fails with the following exception:

  > Argument 'xmlReader' is not valid. A minimum of one .ssdl artifact must be supplied

Please note that this code is being executed by an Azure Function using .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: You must keep your edmx in a .net framework project

Comment: @ErikEJ Is there any way around the issue?  Can I include a framework dll in an azure function that is core 3.1 ( I figured this was not feasible).

Comment: You dont need to, see https://erikej.github.io/ef/dotnetcore/2020/06/15/ef6-use-edmx-dotnetcore.html